# Kompozer Can't "Publish" web page to my Raspberry Pi Server

Tags: apache, ftp, raspberry-pi

I'm not sure how to set the publication settings...

... My RPi is at 192.168.2.126, and is running Apache and ftp.
... The site is to be located in the folder /var/www/GarageDoor on the RPi
... The site is accessed as http://192.168.2.126/GarageDoor/GarageDoors.html

I'm also concerned because my ftp client can't move the file(s) associated with this site directly to /var/www/GarageDoor either. I end up transferring them to my /usr folder, then copying the files manually to the /var/www... folder.

Seems like you need "sudo" permission to copy a file to this folder. I can't figure out how to give either Kompozer or my ftp client such permission. (I'm using bitvise sftp client)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a permissions error. Enter the following into the raspberry pi command line:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/GarageDoor/GarageDoors.html
```

Because that would make the file readable by anyone. If that doesn't work, try the +x option to make the file executable.

```
sudo chmod +x -R /var/www/GarageDoor
```

Note on the second command: This will make all files in /GarageDoor have executable permissions. (-R is for recursive)